# How to get rid of calcium carbonate and other salts formed by calcium hydroxide in air?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My basic question comes from the idea that in olden days people used lime to paint houses, so after it is dried out it becomes white paint which sticks to the walls. So, how to get rid of it? The reaction is

$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 + CO2 -> CaCO3 + H2O}.$$

Comment: We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field due to issues it gives rise to; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. So I rolled back the formatting to a more appropriate form.

Comment: Acetic acid will do.

Comment: @IvanNeretin reaction please.